# Лавка и — лавка

Tags: омонимы

Почему и скамейка, и магазин называются одинаково: лавка? Что между ними общего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со скамейкой все понятно. Это общеславянский морф со значением (деревянный) настил, мостки, полка.
(по Фасмеру).

С "магазином" сложнее. Скорее всего значение развилось из первого уже в русском языке. С учетом того, что превоначально "лавка" означала не магазин, а склад (с полками, наверное), представляется вполне возможным.

По другой версии - родственно "лабаз".
(авторство - моё и интернета)